# Data flow between rendered list and edit modal for more decoupling and less duplication?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm building an app which includes a list of things that each can be edited either in place ("quick edit") or in a separate dialog (i.e. user clicks an edit button on the list item, and the dialog opens to edit the item). The same dialog is used to add a new item to the list. Editing of some basic things can also be done in-place, directly in the list of things, without opening an edit modal.

Right now I have implemented the dialog as a separate Vue app. When I open an item for edit, I have a method on the dialog app that basically does `Object.assign(dialogApp, {index, clone(itemData)})`. When editing is finished, the dialog app manipulates the appropriate data in the original app (something like `app.items[index] = itemData`).

This works right now, but it's clear to me it will cause problems down the line.
It causes a tight coupling between the two apps, and there is no way to share logic (computed properties etc) between them without duplication.

I'm wondering what would be a better way to do this.

I'm using Vue 3, and the in-browser API (no build step).

Comment: I believe you can just add the modal in the main app, pass the data to the modal when you click "edit" (like `currentlyEditing: <myObj>`) and when you save it you just edit the original data and the current object becomes `currentlyEditing: null`, so it just edits the data when you need it

Answer (score 0):

I think a setup with the two apps running side-by-side will inevitably lead to some issues, if you can update it to use a single app you might be better off.

Alternatively, you can define the logic outside of the apps through composables, and pass those to the apps

ie:

```js
function withSharedState() {
  const someVal = Vue.reactive({})
  const someComp = Vue.computed(()=>{/*...*/})
  return {someVal, someComp};
}

const sharedState = withSharedState()

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup(){
    Vue.watch(sharedState.someVal, ()=>{/* do stuff */})
    return { ...sharedState, myInternalVar }
  }
})

const modalApp = Vue.createApp({
  setup(){
    function edit(newData){
      Object.assign(sharedState.someVal, newData)
    }
    return { ...sharedState, edit }
  }
})
```